# streamplot for differntial equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, vector

how I can use StreamPlot or VectorPlot to show x[t] and 1-x[t] and show convergence point in my plot with a different colour like a blue point?

```
G1 = 21290/27
G2 = 23879130/2809
G3 = 13572050/2809
G4 = 1809025/288

U1[t_] := x[t] (G1) + (1 - x[t]) (G2)
U2[t_] := (1 - x[t]) (G3) + x[t] (G4)

x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]) (U1[t] - U2[t])
```

I want to plot something like below pic:

[image]

Comment: Use the option `Epilog -> {Blue, Point[{...,...}]}` in `StreamPlot`, where `...` should be replaced by appropriate coordinates.

Comment: Some examples: [q/64407](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64407),
[a/80285](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80285),
[a/203247](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203247),
[a/223202](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223202),
[a/242409](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/242409)

Comment: Is the plot that you are showing above the one that you want to reproduce?

Comment: @demm, yes, I want to plot like that with x[t] and 1-x[t] that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Michael E2, Thanks, my first question is how to plot x[t] and 1-x[t] like above pic.

Comment: The plot doesn't make sense to me and seems to have an undefined relationship to your diff. eqn. If the axis labels indicate coordinates, how can you can there be a point at `x[t] == 0.4` and `1 - x[t] == 0.2`, say? The conditions are inconsistent. As coordinates `{x[t], 1 - x[t]}` parametrizes the diagonal. The vector field below/above looks like `±{x,1-y}` in {x,y}-coordinates with special cases along the diagonal. You should probably specify the components of the vector field, mathematically if not in code.

Comment: This shows a similar vector field with an arbitrarily chosen point of convergence: `With[{am = ArrayMesh[SparseArray[{{_, _} -> 1}, {15, 15}, 0]]},
  mesh = MeshRegion[
    Rescale@MeshCoordinates[am],
    MeshCells[am, 2]
    ]
  ];
VectorPlot[Piecewise[{
   {{x, y}, x < 1 - y},
   {-{x, y}, x > 1 - y},
   {{1, -1}, x == 1 - y && x < 7/10}},
  {-1, 1}],
 {x, y} \[Element] mesh, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, VectorPoints -> "Mesh",
  Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Medium, Point[{7/10, 1 - 7/10}]}]`

Comment: @Michael E2, I apperetiate you for your help.
Like you, I am confused as to how such a thing is possible. 
I see this plot in a paper at: (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0306261922004706)
you can see this plot at page 9 and related eq at page 6 of this paper.